# EF4 / LINQ: Retrieving two child-nodes in one query

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-4

here is my little issue: I have an EF4, code-first project based on the following data-structure.

Say, as entities I have a house, having multiples rooms, each with multiple windows. That's pretty linear. But the window holds a collection of materials as well as a collection of colors. I now want to load the house, the depending rooms, depending windows, depending color **and** material.

I use the following code to load all houses, with either their depending

- room -> window -> material or
- room -> window -> color by using the following code:

`// house -> room -> window -> material
queryableHouses.Include(Of Room)(Function(u) CType(u.Rooms.Select(Function(v) v.Windows.Select(Function(w) w.Materials)), Room))
// house -> room -> window -> color
queryableHouses.Include(Of Room)(Function(u) CType(u.Rooms.Select(Function(v) v.Windows.Select(Function(w) w.Colors)), Room))`

How can I get a single result-set containing material AND color?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If I were in C#, and using EF4, I would have two Includes with strings representing the full paths of the navigation properties to include. `var query = objectQuery.Include("Rooms.Windows.Materials").Include("Rooms.Windows.Colors");`.

Comment: Anthony, thank you very much for your reply. I try to avoid the strings, but it seems, I don't have no other chance.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about `join` to help with this issue. Like a join in SQL. You could use something like the following, witch is a draft from your description...

```
 'select windows 
 dim query = (From w In (queryableHouses.Include(Of Room)(Function(u) CType(u.Rooms.Select(Function(v) v.Windows), Room)))

'add color from windows
Join  w.color in (queryableHouses.Include(Of Room)(Function(u) CType(u.Rooms.Select(Function(v) v.Windows), Room)) Select u.color) On w.color = u.color

'add material also from window
Join w.material in (queryableHouses.Include(Of Room)(Function(u) CType(u.Rooms.Select(Function(v) v.Windows), Room)) Select u.material)) On w.material = u.material


'then select the result 
Select w)
```

Please correct as needed and its only a suggestion. I just hope you will get more about the meaning of this instead of what is written.